# How to use Background Intelligent Transfer Service in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, microsoft-bits

Hi Can any one help me how to use Background Intelligent Transfer Service using c#. I already have seen so many posts where they have used .dll from Sharpbit. But I need a dll which is msdn.

Answer (score 3):

You can use BITS in .Net using COM Interop.  You don't need any third party code.  There is an entire article and sample code called [Write Auto-Updating Apps with .NET and the Background Intelligent Transfer Service API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188766.aspx#S1)

Comment: That article is gone now. But there is an [archived copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20141231105711/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188766.aspx)

Comment: I can't reach @torvin's link, but here's another copy [here](http://www.w3egitimi.com/2003/02/write-auto-updating-apps-with-net-and.html)